# Find possible number of hours put in by the three workers

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having problems solving the following problem:

> Jan hires three types of laborers (I, II, III) and pays them \$8, \$6, and \$5 per hour, respectively. If the total amount paid is \$2,800 for a total of 500 hours of work, find the possible number of hours put in by the three categories of workers if category III workers must put in the maximum amount of hours.

EDIT: As stated in the comments, George has found the following linear equations:

$$
8x_1 + 6x_2 + 5x_3 = 2800 \\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 500
$$

- DanZimm

Comment: is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: I have set it up as an equation:

Comment: 8X1+6X2+5X3 = 2800

Comment: Sorry keep hitting return too early, and X1+X2+X3 = 500 hours now not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 1):

Well from here we also know that

$$
0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 = 0
$$

So we can create the following matrix

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{rrr|r} 8 & 6 & 5 & 2800 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 500 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]
$$

It's clear we're going to have some sort of "free variable" (there are going to be many solutions and we will describe them with some variable), let's call that $t$.

So we can row reduce this to
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{rrr|r} 3 & 1 & 0 & 300 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 500 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right] \to \left[ \begin{array}{rrr|r} 1 & 1/3 & 0 & 100 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 500 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right] \to \left[ \begin{array}{rrr|r} 1 & 1/3 & 0 & 100 \\ 0 & 2/3 & 1 & 400 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right] \to \left[ \begin{array}{rrr|r} 1 & 1/3 & 0 & 100 \\ 0 & 1 & 3/2 & 600 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]
$$
so it follows that
$$
x_1 + \frac{1}{3}x_2 = 100 \\
x_2 + \frac{3}{2}x_3 = 600
$$
Put $x_3$ as our free variable so $x_3 = t$ and we get
$$
x_2 = 600 - \frac{3}{2}t \\
x_1 = 100 - \frac{1}{3} \left( 600 - \frac{3}{2}t \right) = 100 - 200 + \frac{t}{2} = \frac{t}{2} - 100
$$
Now we refer back to the problem to note that the third worker has to have the most number of hours. We refer to the number of hours of the third category of workers via $x_3$, but notice that we substituted $t=x_3$ so we need to force $t > x_2$ , $t > x_1$ with those above equations still holding. It follows that
$$
t > x_1 = \frac{t}{2} - 100 \iff t > -200
$$
Unfortunately this only tells us that this group of workers worked more than $-200$ hours :P however we also know that
$$
t > x_2 = 600 - \frac{3}{2}t \iff \frac{5}{2}t > 600 \iff t > 240
$$
Now we know something about the hours of the third worker. Let's pick $t=242$ so then it follows that $x_2 = 600 - 363 = 237$ and $x_1 = 121-100=21$. It then follows that
$$
242 + 237 + 21 = 500 \\
8(21) + 6(237) + 5(242) = 2800
$$
and it's clear that $242 > 237 , 242 > 21$ so it appears we have solved this

I probably got carried away after realizing how much work I did for you but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i$ be the number of hours worked by a worker of type $i$. Then you have the two equations
$$
  x_1 + x_2 + x_3
= 500
$$
and
$$
  8x_1 + 6x_2 + 5x_3
= 2800.
$$
That's two equations and three unknowns, plus you have the condition $x_3 > x_2,x_1$. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: I did that got stock at this point

Comment: Can you do some elimination and get $x_2$ and $x_1$ in terms of $x_3$ say?